# Javascript - Randomly choosing items within an object, but not choosing excluded items

Tags: javascript, object, random

I am working on a project where I need to contain a lot of functions within an object so that I can access them with variables that combine in different ways to access different ones. I haven't written this in my main project yet, just tested it as a method and I'll put that test code below to hopefully better explain what I'm talking about. There will be a lot of functions in this object, and the aim is to have one of them randomly run when a button is pressed.

A key part of what I'm trying to make is that the user can exclude whichever functions they want from being randomly selected, and this is what is causing me some problems. I read through a lot of solutions for other problems, but all of them are just a little off (or at least I don't know how to apply them to this just yet). The first thing I tried was using an array and, depending on what option the user ticks, excluding or adding items to it and then randomly selecting from within that to get the random number, but I'm worried that an array of around 300 items would just slow things down or cause more problems than is really useful so I stepped away from this. I looked up how I could exclude numbers from the random generation too, but this tended to use for loops and only worked for a few numbers being excluded - after that I imagine that would cause problems too. I looked into excluding ranges of numbers from random generation as well, but the items that users exclude aren't guaranteed to be next to each other in the object, so that causes problems.

The plan in my head was to add a number at the end of the object key; the random number generator would choose from all non-excluded numbers (exclusion based on other parts of the key, such as excluding all 'salad' options in the test below), and then that number, along with the two or three other variables that make up the key bring us to an actual thing. So, in the theme of the below, "bacon" + "burger" + "lettuce" + "17" might be chosen based on the options the user chooses and the random number respectively and might lead to the 17th baconburgerlettuce based alert - I'm not making some kind of food shouting app, by the way, this really is just a demo...

This is... Hopefully less complicated than it sounds. I imagine I have explained it awfully, so if I can even just clarify something please let me know. Alternatively, if nesting functions inside an object for this purpose is straight up dumb, tell me! I want to learn the best way of doing things, rather than fumble through something ugly and inelegant!

```
var food;
var type;
var func = {
  cheeseburger: function() {alert("This is CHEESE BURGER");},
  baconburger: function() {alert("BACON BURGER reigns supreme!");},
  cheesesalad: function() {alert("CHEESE SALAD hahahaha");},
  baconsalad: function() {alert("BACON SALAD! That's right!");}
 };

$(".cheese").click(function() {
  food = "cheese";
  $(".test").html(food);
});

$(".bacon").click(function() {
  food = "bacon";
  $(".test").html(food);
});

$(".burger").click(function() {
  type = "burger";
  $(".test2").html(type);
});

$(".salad").click(function() {
  type = "salad";
  $(".test2").html(type);
});

$(".go").click(function() {
  func [food + type]();
});
```

Comment: I think your original idea of an array that you remove excluded items from would be best. Don't worry about optimization unless you find that it's actually too slow.

Comment: Where is your code that implements your plan? What problem are you having with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const funcs = [
   v => alert(v),
   v => console.log(v),
   v => alert( v + 1)
];

const excluded = new Set();

//to exclude a function
excluded.add(2);

function random(...args){
  do {
    var i = Math.floor( Math.random() * funcs.length );
  } while( excluded.has( i ) );
  funcs[i](...args);
}

 //test it
 random("test");
```

Comment: This is interesting, and I think I follow it - In the code above, the function 'alert( v + 1)' would have been excluded, right? Could you explain the function random(...args) to me though? And how do you remove things from the excluded pool to add them into funcs again?

Comment: @batbut yep. That takes all arguments as args ( so itll be ["test"]), then it calls the random function with that arguments. To remove simply do excluded.remove(2)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need some property to enable or disable functions.

```
var func = {
    cheeseburger: {f: function() {...}, enabled: true},
    baconburger: {f: function() {...}, enabled: true},
    cheesesalad: {f: function() {...}, enabled: true},
    baconsalad: {f: function() {...}, enabled: true},
  ...
};
```

Then a function to pick random one ignoring disabled ones.

Here arises first problem: If you just randomly pick one until you find one
which is not disabled, as the amount of disabled ones grows, the it will take
longer to find enabled one.

The easier solution is to use a cache like:

```
var cache;
function updateCache(){ // Using function we can update it when needed.
    cache = Object.keys(func).filter(k=>func[k].enabled);
};
updateCache();
```

Then you need enable / disable methods too:

```
function enable(fn) {
    func[fn].enabled = true;
    updateCache();
};
function disable(fn) {
    func[fn].enabled = false;
    updateCache();
};
```

And, finally you just need to pick function keys from the cache:

```
function callRandomFn(){
    var k = Math.floor(Math.random() * cache.length);
    return fn[cache[k]]();
};
```

Comment: This... seems incredibly concise! Would the enable and disable functions have any issues enabling or disabling many functions at once? And what does the k represent in your updateCache() function? An iterator?

Comment: What do you mean with "at once"? Javascript is asynchronous but NOT concurrent. `k` in the context you say is the argument of the *arrow function"  passed to [array].filter() method to tell which elements must be removed (filtered) in the resulting array.

Comment: I think I understand, but I'm having trouble actually implementing this in the test. I can't actually get a function to run out of the object now, which is the main hurdle. Using the method from before ( func[cheesesalad]() ) doesn't work, nor does func[cheesesalad[]} or func[cheesesalad[f], or even func.cheesesalad. I know that I'm clearly missing something obvious, but would you advise on the syntax here?

Comment: @batbut func["cheesesalad"].f(...)